# Configuring Maven when using JFrog CLI

Tags: jfrog-cli

When trying to run a build of a maven application using jfrog CLI, one of the prerequisite steps is to run

```
jf mvn-config
```

When we run it manually on a server, it has an interactive step to configure the resolution for release dependencies (tab and select)

I am wondering is there a way to feed in the config parameters as CLI arguments to **jf mvn-config** so that we can set the properties programmatically for the repository?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this comment](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/1529#issuecomment-1115044889) from the JFrog CLI Github page and the --global attribute option described [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningMavenBuilds:%7E:text=Setting%20maven%20repositories) would be an useful information. It is important to note that the configuration set up using `jf mvn-config` may override the global settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check `jf mvnc --help`. There are CLI flags you can supply to make it non-interactive, e.g. :

`jf mvnc --repo-resolve-releases libs-release --repo-resolve-snapshots libs-snapshot --repo-deploy-snapshots libs-snapshot-local --repo-deploy-releases libs-release-local`